# Java -- Runtime typing differences

Tags: java, runtime

I have two situations drawn up, and the strange differences between them are causing me a bit of grief.  I will attempt to detail them below in code.

Situation 1:

```
public void doSomething(Object obj) {
  //do something with obj
}

public void doSomething(String str) {
  //do something similar to str, but apply some custom
  //processing for String's
}

Object o = new String("s");
doSomething(o); // this will use the Object version...
```

Situation 2:

```
class Dog {
  void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("woof");
  }
}

class Chihuahua extends Dog {
  void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("yip");
  }
}

Dog dog = new Chihuahua();
dog.makeSound(); //will print 'yip', the Chihuahua version...
```

Why, in situation one, is the runtime type of the parameter not used, but in situation two it is?  I understand that the examples are actually different things, but I am more curious about what is going on 'under the covers' here.

Comment: Note that you could change the behavior to use the String version of `doSomething` with a cast: `doSomething((String)o);`.

Comment: This is a contrived example.  I just happened to stumble upon this situation today and it threw me for a loop for a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, a **method signature** is chosen at compile-time from among a number of overloaded signatures.  The Java language specification says that this is done based on the static type of the variables.

In the second example, an **implementation** of a given method signature is chosen at runtime based on virtual method dispatch.  This is done based on the runtime type of the class containing the method definition.

Answer (score 2):

Situation #1 is method overloading, which is static at compile time.  Situation #2 is polymorphism, which is dynamic at runtime.